# Balance the spacing in matrices including minus signs?

Tags: matrices, typography

I often find matrices including entries with minus signs unbalanced. I already experimented with differently aligning the columns and `\phantom{-}`minus signs, but find it hard to get a satisfying result, at least in my view.

Consider the examples shown in the image:

[image]

I do prefer 1b) to 1a), but wish the minus would "weigh" less and the left column would move slightly to the left, while the right column moves more towards the center.
For the cases in 2, where one entry is larger than the other (`ab`is larger than `2`), but not with the minus sign (where `-2` is larger than `ab`), I feel it's even more difficult to balance it properly. So I have the following two questions:

1. Is the behaviour as described above something you consider worthy of changing? Is it standard in scientific publications (I couldn't find much on this topic)?
2. How would one achieve an automatic balancing, where the minus sign somewhat "weighs" less, but without interfering or coming to close to the matrix brackets?

Edit: Simply using right justification as provided for example in the `mathtools` package with `\begin{pmatrix*}[r]` does not always work IMO. I do like the center justification of example 2b) where the `2` is placed centered above the `ab`, but ignoring the minus. However that examples leaves too much white space between the two columns.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item [1a)]
    $\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 \\
        -1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}$
    \item [1b)]
    $\begin{pmatrix}
        \phantom{-}1 & 2 \\
        -1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}$
    \item [2a)]
    $\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -2 \\
        1 & ab
    \end{pmatrix}$
    \item [2b)]
    $\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -2 \\
        1 & \phantom{-}ab
    \end{pmatrix}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: using `mathtools` you also have `\begin{pmatrix*}[r]`

Comment: @daleif Thanks, that's actually how I experimented with column alignment. However, even though it's picky, I feel that right justification only works for column entries with the same size. I do like the center justification in example 2b) (ignoring the minus), where the `2` is centered above the `ab`.

Comment: I added an edit in the original question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You could to use also `spalign` package which provides a facility for typesetting matrices, and using other alignment environments and macros, with spaces as the alignment delimiter and semicolons (by default) as the end-of-row indicator (see the documentation).

I have used `\spalignmat[r]` (with the option `r` (right)). Very important are the blank spaces.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spalign}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item [1a)] $\spalignmat[r]{1 2; -1 0} $
\item [2a)] $\spalignmat[r]{1 -2; 1 ab} $
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, does help indeed! I didn't know the package. I will experiment with its possibilities, in particular the possibilities offered by `matdelimskip`. I'm not sure though, if some kind of automation is possible to treat the minus sign with less weight (e.g. in your example 1a) the space induced by the minus sign on the left of the first column seems quite large compared to the one on the right side).